# How not to include mock services in Angular2 production bundle

Tags: angular, mocking, angular-cli

When building an angular 2 app for production we use

```
ng build --prod --w --aot
```

But our mock services also get bundled and minified probably because we have

```
import {XMockService} from "./xxx-mock.service";
```

and that prevents the tree shaking from dropping the unused service. Here is our simplified app.module.ts which conditionally lazy-loads the mock service when environment.mock=true

I would imagine this is a common scenario but I can't find any answers for it.

app.module.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {XService} from "./xxx.service";
import {XMockService} from "./xxx-mock.service";

let importedModules: Array<any> = [
  XService
];

if (environment.mock) {
  importedModules.push(
    {provide: XService, useClass: XMockService}
  );
} else {
  importedModules.push(
    XService
  );
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: importedModules,
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chosen answer no longer works. For Angular CLI 6, as [recommended](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8031#issuecomment-336855408), we'll have to treat dev & prod as separate projects sharing the same codebase.

**Solution summary**

- Have separate projects for each env. (As simple as a few lines in angular.json)
- Have as many AppModules as the number of envs with separate main.ts files for each
- Have separate tsconfig files for each env
- Tell angular about the changes through angular.json

---

**Details**

Make a copy of AppModule and name it DevModule. (DevModule for dev & AppModule for prod). DevModule will be the one with the mock services.

Have separate main.ts files for each. Say prod-main.ts for prod & dev-main.ts for dev. The only difference being that the prod-main loads AppModule while dev-main loads DevModule.

Duplicate the tsconfig.app.json file into tsconfig.prod.json & tsconfig.dev.json. In the exclude section of tsconfig.prod.json, type in "dev-main.ts", "app/dev-module.ts", "**/mock-*.ts". Type in the other dev modules too (the ones that load the mocks).

Repeat for dev. For tsconfig.dev.json, exclude prod-main.ts, app/app-module.ts. Make relevant changes to tsconfig.spec.json files too, if necessary (with similar excludes).

Update angular.json files to reflect the new tsconfig files.

```
// angular.json. Only the relevant parts are given below.
// Essentially, separate tsconfig files for 2 projects - dev & prod
{
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-prod-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "main": "src/main-prod.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          },
        },
        "test": {
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.prod.spec.json",
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.prod.json",
              "src/tsconfig.prod.spec.json"
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-dev-proj": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "main": "src/dev-main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.dev.json",
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.dev.spec.json",
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.dev.json",
              "src/tsconfig.dev.spec.json"
            ],
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-prod-proj",
}
```

Run the projects by name

```
ng serve my-dev-proj // dev with mocks
ng serve             // prod (set as default in angular.json)
same goes for the build command
```

Comment: It seems there is currently an issue with the exclude of tsconfig.json. There are some proposed work arounds - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050

Answer (score 8):

So according to one of the [main contributors](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3940#issuecomment-272726261) the solution for your problem would be something like:

```
// main.ts
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment, AppModule } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

// environments/environment.ts
export { DevModule as AppModule } from '../app/dev.module';

export const environment = {
  production: false
};
// environments/environment.prod.ts
export { ProdModule as AppModule } from '../app/prod.module';

export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

So it's very similar to my previous answer the difference is that you will be using different environment files, instead of different main files.

### Previous Answer

It was recently [opened an issue on Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3940), requesting a feature that would allow you to that. How? By switching your webpack entry point. Right now Angular-cli will always use the same entry point `src/main.ts`, the idea behind this feature is that you can specify a different entry point, so you would have something like `src/main.dev.ts`:

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppDevModule } from './app/app.dev.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppDevModule);
```

And then you would import your mocks on `AppDevModule`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {XMockService} from "./xxx-mock.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [XMockService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppDevModule {}
```

The only downside of doing things this way, is that you would have to keep your `AppModule` and `AppDevModule` synced.

Which you could solve by creating a third file, something like `AppImportsModule`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";

export {AppComponent} //we also export this for simplicity

export const declarations = [
  AppComponent
];

export const imports = [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule
];
```

And then on your `AppModule.ts` or `AppDevModule.ts` you would only need to import your providers:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {declarations, imports, AppComponent} from "./app.imports.module";
import {XMockService} from "./xxx-mock.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations, // with es6 this is the same as "declarations: declarations"
  imports, //same as above
  providers: [XMockService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppDevModule {}
```

So until that feature isn't implemented, I have no better solution to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Fabio for the great answer. Up voted the github bug so hopefully it gets addressed. Do you know if Angular-cli allows you to have prebuild step or I have to do it in the shell.  I was thinking of implementing some kind of pre-build step to dynamically generate the AppModule.ts file for the time being. Having 2 separate AppsModules is not a big burden. We have to do that for the test files anyway and those are much more difficult to keep in sync due to the number of test files.

Comment: @DavidDehghan I have updated my answer, but you probably already saw this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3940#issuecomment-272726261

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore in the newer cli. Throws weird errors & their new solution of multiple projects doesn't make sense for this usecase i think. Src: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3940#issuecomment-279058285

Answer (score 0):

Conditional build example (Webpack):

```
export default class XMockService {

  ...

}

if(environment.mock)
{
    let XMockService = System.import('./x.mock.service');
    importedModules.push(
       {provide: XService, useClass: XMockService}
    );
}
```

It will create additional chunk like `0.chunk.js`.

Comment: Hi Kemsky - Thanks for the answer. Do you mind telling us a bit more detail on how to implement that. I am not that familiar with webpack build process.

Comment: This wouldn't work (off the top of my head) because System.import and import() return a promise. This code is assuming synchronous execution.